# Video data hash changes everytime I use `AVMutableComposition` & `AVAssetExportSession` to export even if goes through same steps with no changes

Tags: swift, hash, avfoundation

Minimum snippet to regenerate. Exports a new `exportURL` from given `videoURL`.

While exporting I am

- Adding the video track
- Adding the audio track
- Keeping the complete time range for export

```swift
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    guard let compositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid),
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
        else {
            print("Something is wrong with the asset.")
            return
    }

    do {
        let startTime = .zero
        let endTime = asset.duration
        let timeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: startTime, end: endTime)
        try compositionTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: assetTrack, at: .zero)

        // if audio isn't muted in the editor, add audio track from the asset
        if let audioAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first,
            let compositionAudioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) {
            try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audioAssetTrack, at: .zero)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    guard let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: videoQuality.exportPreset)
        else {
            print("Cannot create export session.")
            onComplete(nil)
            return
    }
    
    let videoName = UUID().uuidString
    let exportURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        .appendingPathComponent(videoName)
        .appendingPathExtension("mp4")
    
    export.outputFileType = .mp4
    export.outputURL = exportURL
    
    export.exportAsynchronously {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch export.status {
            case .completed:
                onComplete(exportURL)
            default:
                print("Something went wrong during export.")
                print(export.error ?? "unknown error")
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Now after I have this `exportURL` can get data from it. And that data is hashed. But even if the same video goes through this same process which does not apply any edit to the video why the hash is changed?

In case the function is needed which I am using to generate the hash.

```swift
extension Data {
    
    var digest: Data {
        let digestLength = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: digestLength)
        CC_SHA256(bytes, UInt32(count), &hash)
        return Data(bytes: hash, count: digestLength)
    }
    
    var hexString: String {
        let hexString = map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        return hexString
    }
}
```

Comment: From `exportedURL` you are regenerating the data and comparing by `data.digest. hexString` ? And for same videoURL input it is giving diff hash for `exported videoURL` data?

Comment: Exactly. It makes sense if I trimmed or selected different tracks. But for exact same transformations over the same video what is changing the output data?